# How can I preview a regular expression in search/replace?

Tags: emacs, elisp, replace

Is there a package (or free-floating elisp) around that dynamically previews both the matches and the effect of a regular expression search/replace in Emacs? I believe a few specialized modes offer something like this, but I haven't been able to find a universal solution.

I should note that I'm familiar with regexp-builder, but it only previews matches and requires me to copy strings between buffers---not a perfect solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to 'preview the matches' is by entering the regexp via `isearch-forward-regexp` (<kbd>C-M-s</kbd>) which interactively highlights matches as you write the regexp, and then calling `isearch-query-replace-regexp` with <kbd>C-M-%</kbd> (i.e. the normal `query-replace-regexp` binding).

To see the matches throughout the buffer (as opposed to just the visible portion), you can type <kbd>M-s</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> while entering the isearch regexp to run `isearch-occur`. The minibuffer remains selected, so you can continue editing the regexp.

I'm not sure about 'previewing' the replacements. I suspect most people simply do the replacement, and undo it again if it was a mistake? (and I'm not sure there's a big different between that and a preview feature).

**Edit:** <strike>I guess the `occur` buffer does facilitate a 'replacement preview' option of sorts. It's restricted to the occur buffer, but maybe that's good enough.</strike>

Emacs 24 has a rather useful `occur-edit-mode`: Type <kbd>e</kbd> in the occur buffer and you can edit the matches as text (so you can perform a search & replace in that buffer). After editing the occur buffer, you type <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-c</kbd> to write the changes back to the original buffer(s); but *until* you do that, the changes only exist in the occur buffer itself, as a preview of what will happen if you confirm them.

As-is, that doesn't combine as smoothly as you might want with the original part of this answer, but it certainly seemed worth mentioning.

**Edit 2:** Ooh, okay, my previous edit was a lie. Or at least not remotely consistent enough for what I'd written. I thought that occur edit mode didn't make the changes to the original buffers immediately, and *sometimes* that's true, but most of the time it updates the original buffer at the same time as the occur buffer. I'm not sure why it's not consistent, but obviously you can't treat it as a preview, as I had suggested.

Comment: Thanks. I'd say this effectively answers the first half of my question, although I'm still hoping to discover a way to preview the outcome of the potential change. I know for a fact it's supported in the Evil package, but I'm not knowledgable enough to look through the ex command parser code in elisp.

Comment: There's also the `re-builder` command that will interactively show the matches of a regexp (with colourised groups etc) in a buffer. You do have to enter the regular expression string-escaped though.

Comment: Huw: that was mentioned in the question. Also, `re-builder` supports (and converts between) multiple syntax options (`C-c TAB`); it defaults to `read` (which requires the double-escaping). If you change the syntax to `string` you can enter the regexp without the extra escaping (but copying with `C-c C-w` will still copy it as a fully-escaped string).

Comment: On that last note, it occurred to me that the default re-builder syntax was surely customisable, and of course it is. `reb-re-syntax` is the variable for that. `(setq reb-re-syntax 'string)` if you want it to use string syntax by default.

Comment: Thanks phils. I'm accepting your response as correct because it's helpful and I accept that there just is no standalone package to preview the way I want.

Comment: Perhaps you should contact the authors of Evil directly to ask whether their replacement preview code can be used independently of that library?

Answer (score 6):

[visual-regexp](https://github.com/benma/visual-regexp.el) allows previewing replacements inline:

[image]